# I can't add more than 1 annotation to MKMapview :|

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

So I'm pulling my hair out over this one. I've been tracking down a bug in my app. Originally, I was trying to load long / lat coordinates from a database and do a for loop, adding each annotation to the map view. This seemed simple enough, but for some reason when I tried to add the annotations in the loop it would only show 1 annotation in the end.

So, using the code below, I decided to try and simply add two annotations to MKMapView to be sure that I can do this in the first place, and it doesn't work!

```
[NewAnnotation setLongitude:-104.6200448];
[NewAnnotation setLongitude:50.4908343];
NewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[NewAnnotation alloc] init];
[self.mapAnnotations insertObject:newAnnotation atIndex:0];
[newAnnotation release];

[CelebsAnnotation setLongitude:-90.6200448];
[CelebsAnnotation setLatitude:51.4908343];
CelebsAnnotation *celebsAnnotation = [[CelebsAnnotation alloc] init];
[self.mapAnnotations insertObject:celebsAnnotation atIndex:1];
[celebsAnnotation release];

[self.mapView addAnnotations:mapAnnotations];
```

The annotations show up in their correct locations if I only add one of them to the mapAnnotations array (I have to adjust the index to 0 if I only add the CelebsAnnotation), but when I try to add both, they show up in the same location on the map!? Any ideas as to why this would happen? I am so confused and frustrated..

Comment: You seem to have `setLongitude` and `setLatitude` as class methods. What do they do? How is you `init` method defined?

Comment: I didn't have the init method defined and actually now that I looked at my custom annotation class I didn't have the coordinate property in the .h so I'm confused as to why it even worked with even one annotation. I'm going to look further into properly implementing a custom annotation class because maybe that is my problem.

Comment: -(void)setLongitude:(double)lon {
 Clongitude = lon;
}

Comment: And what is `Clongitude`? Is it a static variable and how to you implement the `longitude` instance method?

Comment: Clongtitude is a double value and I'm not sure which longitude instance method you're asking about. I thought that all that was required is the @property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate; and also I implemented this function to set the coordinate - (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
 theCoordinate.latitude = Clatitude;
    theCoordinate.longitude = Clongitude;
    return theCoordinate; 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here,

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate; { 
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate; 
    theCoordinate.latitude = Clatitude; 
    theCoordinate.longitude = Clongitude; 
    return theCoordinate; 
}
```

You are creating a new `CLLocationCoordinate2D` every time `coordinate` is requested an you are setting this to the static variables `Clongitude & Clatitude`. Since these are static variables, you will be returning similar `CLLocationCoordinate2D` objects for all instances of  `CelebsAnnotation`. So basically all instances will have the same coordinate.

You should rather have an `init..` method that takes in a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` object and set it to an instance variable. For example, look at [`this tutorial`](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=81).

You will end up doing something like this,

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
coordinate.longitude = -90.6200448;
coordinate.latitude = 51.4908343;
CelebsAnnotation *celebsAnnotation = [[CelebsAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate];
[self.mapAnnotations insertObject:celebsAnnotation atIndex:1];
[celebsAnnotation release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, this code fetching value of lattitude and longitude from database and, placing annotation in map:

```
            while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                char *iTtl=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
                trackedImageTitle=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:iTtl];
                char *iLat=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
                trackedLocationLattitude=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:iLat];
                //NSLog(@"lat=%@",trackedLocationLattitude);
                char *iLon=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
                trackedLocationLongitude=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:iLon];
                //NSLog(@"lon=%@",trackedLocationLongitude);    
                char *lcn=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4);
                trackedLocation=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:lcn];    
                int iId=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                NSString *iIdS =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", iId];
                [allImageIds addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",iIdS]];
                //theImage=iId;
                //NSLog(@"the image=%d, iId= %d",theImage,iId); 
                location.latitude=[trackedLocationLattitude floatValue];
                location.longitude=[trackedLocationLongitude floatValue];   
                addAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithLocation:location withTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tuscany"] withSubTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Italy"] withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",iId]]];
                addAnnotation.mTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",trackedImageTitle];
                addAnnotation.mSubTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",trackedLocation];
                ////NSLog(@"%@",addAnnotation.mTitle);
                [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
            }
```

`mapView` is instance of `MKMapView`.

Comment: thanks for posting this code however I already have all of the code written which connects to my MySQL db and parses a JSON response that contains the annotations.

Comment: it's not about db connection, it's about while loop which fetch different values and put em um in values, which leads to drop multiple annotation